Removing a DLL on startup
On Windows 10 startup, this RunDLL error message occurs:

"There was a problem starting C:\Program Files\HP\HP Deskjet 3540 series\bin\HPStatusBL.dll. The specified module could not be found."

I have uninstalled HP Deskjet 3540 series and now installed HP ePrint. So now I no longer have the folder ..\HP Deskjet 3540 series.
How do I remove this message?

You can use Sysinternals Autoruns to find the broken reference and to disable (or delete) it.
I would recommend first disabling the items and rebooting Windows as a test. Only after everything is working as intended you can (optionally) remove the unnecessary items permanently. It might also be wise to modify as few things as possible at the same time. That way you can keep track of the causal relations between your modifications and the outcomes.
